# Symfony2 Entity creation: console vs manual

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The questions is related to my other ANSWERED question - [Symfony2 YAML Entity field not being bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206552/symfony2-yaml-entity-field-not-being-bound/25207636#25207636)

I don't know why, but there was some glitch in building my entities manually. The YAML file and Entity class looks exactly the same in automated entity generation, but when i tried to add everything manually there was a problem with selecting new fields. If ANYONE can extend upon the knowledge of Symfony2\doctrine2 generating entities it should be very helpful. I mean, what does it generate beside yaml and entity? Why is it different from MANUAL entity creation.