# Symfony2 Doctrine2 Cache

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The questions is related to my other ANSWERED question - [Symfony2 YAML Entity field not being bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206552/symfony2-yaml-entity-field-not-being-bound/25207636#25207636)

I have problems with my queries. Once I add VIA CONSOLE new entity fields - they are not being selected automatically. I've narrowed down problem to this...

I have query like this:

> "SELECT o from Infobiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Organization as o LEFT JOIN
>   o.picture as p WHERE o.slug = ?1";

This query, in the debugger, does not get the select of a new field. Try again, but:

> "SELECT o from Infobiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Organization as o LEFT JOIN
>   o.picture as p WHERE o.slug = ?1 ";

I added space inside of DQL string and THIS query DOES get the select of a new field. How can I avoid adding spaces to every other query there is??? 
I've tried everything here - [Symfony2 doctrine clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826444/symfony2-doctrine-clear-cache) - does not work. Clearly, though, it's a caching problem. Just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I was using memcache and it was caching all DQLS:

```
php app/console memcached:clear --clearAll default
```

default being the "cluster" name in config. the NAME not id.